# Using SharedPrefernces to sum Integers from a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sum, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create an App that sums time.
My situation:
I have a RecyclerView with a lot of elements, and each of those has a different `time` attribute.

Now, when an element is clicked, then another and another I want all those attributes to be summed and the final result to be displayed in another activity.
So what I'm trying to do is to achieve this using SharedPrefernces like this:

```
private void getTime(int time) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int time0 = sharedPreferences.getInt("TimeRetrieve", 0);

        int sum = time0 + time;




        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = mContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences2.edit();
        editor.putInt("Time", sum);

        editor.apply();
```

`TimeRetrieve` gets the total time that is displayed ion the TextView, so if it's the first time it's defaulted to 0, of course.
After that it's supposed to sum that retrieved int with the int of the Item that has just been clicked and then saved in another SharedPref: `Time`.

`Time` gets sent to the TextView, where it gets retrieved by `TimeRetrieve`

But his doesn't work..

Comment: Any reason you using SharedPreferences for it? a local variable wouldn't be enough?

Comment: I tried but I'm to dumb for that, and like that it's ready to be saved in the TextView

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're using two different `SharedPreferences` to get and put data?  Consider using something like this:

```
private void GetTime(int time) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getDefaultSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int time0 = sharedPreferences.getInt("TimeRetrieve", 0);

        int sum = time0 + time;





        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("TimeRetrieve", sum);

        editor.apply();
```

Notice the call to `getDefaultSharedPreferences`.  This will get the default `com.companyname.package.yourapplication` SharedPreferences file, and you should be using only that file if you want to set and retrieve data from it.  There are other reasons you would create multiple SharedPreferences files, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do.  You're also using two different keys, which is definitely a part of the problem as well.  I changed them in the code above so that they match and you're referencing the same key both times.

Comment: It doesn't allow  `getDefaultSharedPreferences`.
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

I don't know why it's null..?

Comment: @BetaReogen Your context object is null

Answer (score 2):

First, you are using 2 different keys : `TimeRetrieve` and `Time`. So, you can't make the sum.
Second, why are you using 2 `SharedPreferences` object ? Only one is needed.
Third, you don't need to use `SharedPreferences` here. You just have to sum what you want in a variable and then, pass it to the other Activity with extra bundle.

Comment: I've tried that in may but I'm too stupid, I either get the same number summed with itself or 0